# Remove negative values from linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a program that lets the user create a linked list. It can add elements in the front, middle and end, and print said list.

I need a function to remove any negative numbers in that list.

I tried the following, but it removes some positive numbers in the middle.

I've been stuck at this for like 3-4 hours trying different stuff, and its hopeless now.

```cpp
void del1()
{
    element * p = START;
    element * q = nullptr;
    element * k = nullptr;
    if (START)
    {
        while (p)
        {
            if (p->key < 0)
            {
                if (p == START)
                {
                    p = START;
                    START = START->next;
                    delete p;
                    p = START;
                }
                else if (p->next == NULL)
                {
                    p = START;
                    while (p->next)
                    {
                        q = p;
                        p = p->next;
                    }
                    q->next = NULL;
                    p = START;
                }
                else
                {
                    q = START;
                    while (q->next == p)
                    {
                        k = q;                                              
                        q = q->next;
                    }
                    k->next = p->next;
                    p = START;
                }
            }
            else if (p->key > 0)
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through it one line at a time in the debugger and check the linked list and the variables after each step. What did you notice when the positive numbers are removed? Pay close attention to the `while (q->next == p)`.

Comment: What's causing you to lose nodes with positive numbers is that `while (q->next == p)` has the condition reversed. It should be `while (q->next != p)`.

Comment: Figured I had some logical error somewhere just wasn't sure where. Also the comment below fixed the problem for me. Just have to look into this type of stuff more I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is WAY over-complicated for a simple traverse+removal operation.  Mainly because each time you find an `element` that you want to remove, you are having to re-traverse through the list again just to find the previous `element` whose `next` field needs to be updated.  You don't need that extra traversal at all, just keep track of the last `element` you see while your main loop is traversing the list.

Also, there is a logic flaw that will cause an endless loop if any `key` is `0`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void del1()     
{       
    element * p = START;        
    element * previous = nullptr;
    element * next;

    while (p)
    {               
        next = p->next;

        if (p->key < 0)
        {
            if (previous) previous->next = next;
            if (START == p) START = next;
            delete p;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = p;
        }

        p = next;
    }       
}
```

Alternatively, which is slightly more simplified by eliminating the 2 `if`s before the `delete`:

```cpp
void del1()     
{       
    element * p = START;        
    element * next;
    element ** previous = &START;

    while (p)
    {               
        next = p->next;

        if (p->key < 0)
        {
            *previous = next;
            delete p;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = &(p->next);
        }

        p = next;
    }       
}
```